# Flutter web :MissingPlugingException

Tags: flutter, dart, web

Good morning! I have a problem with the web flutter, when I run the application on a mobile it works well, but when it comes to the web it does not work, the problem is on the server side when I call a feature at the server level. Here is the land:

**MissingPlugingException(No implementation found for method check on channel plugins.
flutter.io/connectivity)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin does not support `web`, use [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) instead.